# Django RestFramwork how to get child component components after filter them out

Tags: django, reactjs, api, recursion, model

I'm using django restframe work as a backend to my React app. when I created a recursive data I filtered the views in order to not showing the child components outside the parent components  `queryset = Data.objects.filter(main__isnull=True)`. My problem is when I go to the `api_link/1/` it will `GET` the component if it is a parent but when I say `api_link/2/` I get `"detail": "Not found."` because I filtered them out but i still can see them inside the child that I called it`sub` as shown in the bellow"

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "tag": "div",
        "text": "Hello",
        "src": "",
        "style": "",
        "main": null,
        "sub": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "tag": "h1",
                "text": "test2",
                "src": null,
                "style": "",
                "main": 1,
                "sub": []
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "tag": "h1",
                "text": "test 3",
                "src": null,
                "style": "",
                "main": 1,
                "sub": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "tag": "div",
        "text": "bla bla",
        "src": "",
        "style": "",
        "main": null,
        "sub": []
    }
]
```

`api folder`
`views.py`

```
from data.models import Data
from .serializers import DataSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class DataVeiwSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
```

`urls.py`

```
from .views import DataVeiwSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('', DataVeiwSet, basename='user')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

`searializer.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from data.models import Data
from rest_framework_recursive.fields import RecursiveField
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      sub = RecursiveField(many=True, required=False)
      class Meta:
            model = Data
            fields = ('id','tag','text','src','style','main','sub')
```

`myapp folder` came from python manage.py startapp myapp
`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework.request import Request


class Data(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    src = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    style = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    main = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True, related_name="sub", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: So you want to be able to GET a component regardless of whether it is a parent? Or do you want to exclude the children from the response of the parent?

Comment: yes I want to get the component by Id regardless the parent. + I know what you mean i can say `axios.get('link/id/')[0].sub ` but I don't wanna do that.

Comment: So if I understand correctly when you retrieve all of the `data` instances you want to exclude the children (so when not passing an ID), but with a specific GET you want to still be able to retrieve them?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Can you post your full view code?

Comment: one way to do this is `queryset = Data.objects.all()` then `axios.get('api/link/').then(res => setState(res.data)).catch(err => console.log(err))` then
 `data.filter(i => i.main == null)` despite this is messy so if their is any better ides pls share .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the methods for list retrieval and specific retrieval. I think you're looking for something like this:

```
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Data.objects.filter(main__isnull=True)
        serializer = DataSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    # (You probably don't need to overwrite this)
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Data.objects.all()
        data = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = DataSerializer(data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

You can read more on it here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example